# Java see if arraylist contains string

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a class called `Paragens` like this:

```
public class Paragens {
    static int contadorParagens = 1;

    String nomeParagem;
    int id;

    public Paragens(String nomeParagem) {
        this.nomeParagem = nomeParagem;
        this.id = contadorParagens++;
    }

    // getters and setters for nomeParagem
}
```

Every Paragens object has a name and an Id.

This class has a main method where I create several Paragens objects and store them inside an ArrayList like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Paragens> paragens = new ArrayList<Paragens>();
    paragens.add(new Paragens("name1");
    // ... add more paragens
}
```

This is working ok. If I insert a bunch of paragens and print them I can see tat is all ok.

What I am trying to do is to ask the user to input a paragem name and then I want to see if that paragem is already in the ArrayList.

```
String name;
System.out.println("Insert paragem name: ");
pickName = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println(paragens.contains(pickName));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) checks to see if the list contains the actual thing you handed it. In this case, you're passing in a `String` name, but comparing it to `Paragem` instances. `contains` can't magically guess that it's supposed to look at a given property on the `Paragem` instances to compare the string.

You can easily loop the list to find out for yourself:

```
boolean found = false;
for (Paragem p : paragems) {
    if (p.nomeParagem.equals(pickName)) { // Or use an accessor function for `nomeParagem` if appropriate
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

...or as a function:

```
boolean containsParagemWithName(ArrayList<Paragem> paragems, String pickName) {
    for (Paragem p : paragems) {
        if (p.nomeParagem.equals(pickName)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: And if you make that into a method of its own, you can do away with the `found` flag and just `return true` in the loop or `return false` after it.

Comment: @Anonymouse: Don't override equals to make a Paragem equal a String. That would be *very* unconventional (for example equality would then no longer be symmetric). Equals, hashCode and these methods are very general-purpose, expect to follow certain contracts, and should not do unexpected things to accommodate some special purposes.

Comment: Yeah, for `equals` he should create a new Paragem, and then check if that one is equal, obviously.

Comment: Ah, okay, that would be fine (if name equality does indeed mean Paragem equality).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That makes all the sense. Unfortunately I did'n remember doing the for loop. Will implement that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to implement the `contains` method yourself. Do a for loop over the entire array and check if the name of one of the elements is equal with what you're trying to add. If not, add a `new Paragens(pickName)`.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the `contains` method. He just needs to either implement `equals` or manually inspect the instances in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Objects by default are compared by their *memory location*. So if you have two Paragem with the same name, they are still not equal.

So either, you check the name of each one:

```
boolean checkDuplicate(String pickName) {
    for (Paragem p : paragems) {
      if (p.nomeParagem.equals(pickName)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

or implement (override) the `equals` method to compare names (you should be calling `contains` on a new Paragem object then instead of a `String`, though).

Comment: *"Objects by default are compared by their memory location. So if you have two Paragem with the same name, they are still not equal."* Yes, but it's *not* comparing two `Paragem` instances. He's comparing `String` to `Paragem`.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Correct. Which is why it even works less. ;-) Unfortunately, `contains` in Java Collections is defined for `Object`s, which introduces this kind of bugs.

Comment: Understood the for loop but the last thing (implement (override) the equals method to compare names.) didn't understand because I'm new at Java. Nevertheless will implement the for loop